# Distance Among Guidelines in Figma?

Tags: guidelines

so I am using Figma for now because Adobe XD will no more free. I am curious if there is a configuration to show distance among guide lines in Figma like Adobe XD has?

[image]

Above is the illustration. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to find a Figma support forum. We can't help with software usage questions.

Comment: If you hold down the OPTION or ALT key on the keyboard while moving an object, you will see the distance to nearest objects

Answer (score 4):

The quick way I use is to draw a rectangle from one guide to the other, it will snap, then use the height or width of the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the distance among your guides using 'Rulers'.
This [link](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040449713#Viewing_Distances_Redlines) might help you.